# CakePHP 2.1, Ajax & Miles Johnsons Uploader Plugin

Tags: ajax, cakephp, plugins, uploader

I want to use the Plugin with CakePHP 2.1 as behaviour through $actAs = 'Uploader.Attachment'. While this works fine for static Uploads, I dont know how to use it for ajaxUploads.

The simple Question:
Is there anyway to make an ajax-Upload happen through the actAs-Behaviour?

The explanation (if needed):
The attachment Behaviour doesn't seem to have any defaults nor any other code regarding ajax (especially not the ajaxField in  the following code). Though it works if I include the Plugin via

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Uploader = new Uploader(array(
        'ajaxField' => 'qqfile'
    ));
}
```

So I can use something like:

```
$data = $this->Uploader->upload($this->Uploader->ajaxField, array('overwrite' => true));
```

But not with:

```
$this->request->data;
```

This is not quite what I was seaching for, as I
1. Still need the actAs-Behaviour for other actions.
2. Have two different inclusions of the plugin, which I have to check that they do the same.
3. Can't automatically create thumbs and attach them to the same entry of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did now for my specific case. Maybe it helps someone. Not beautiful but it works:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Uploader = new Uploader(array(
        'ajaxField' => 'qqfile'
    ));
}

public function ajax() {        
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Upload: AJAX File Upload');
    $this->render('ajax');
}

public function ajax_upload($album_id = null, $album_title = null) {
    $this->set('album_id', $album_id);
    $this->set('album_title', $album_title);
    $album_id = 2;
    $upload_dir = "uploads/$album_id/";

    $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->Uploader->setup(array('uploadDir' => "$upload_dir"));
    $data = $this->Uploader->upload($this->Uploader->ajaxField, array(
        'overwrite' => true,
        'name' => 'uploaderFilename'
    ));
    //Creating a thumb
    $thumb_name = $data['custom_name']."_thumb.".$data['ext'];
    $this->Uploader->resize(array('width' => 250, 'expand' => true, 'aspect' => true, 'append' => '_thumb'));
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $this->Picture->set($data);   
        if ($this->Picture->validates()) {
            // Upload successful
            $data["album_id"]= $album_id;
            $data['path_thumb'] = $upload_dir.$thumb_name;
            $this->Picture->save($data);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $data));                                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there a reason for creating a new instance of Uploader inside `beforeFilter()` instead of `ajax_upload()`?

Comment: @felipe.zkn: I don't remember to be honest. Haven't done anything with cake since then.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered a couple of your related questions already - I really don't want to go through the plugin's configuration settings (contact the developer himself for specific questions) so I'm just going to assume they are correct since you say it works for static file submission.

1. $actAs denotes **Behavior paramaters**; they are defined on Model classes, which by definition should never communicate directly with a view anyway. You can still have your model actAs, if you want, you just can't use a model to manipulate a view's behavior.
2. This is an **AJAX-driven file upload**, right? So you probably need to write a simple client-side script to go with the form that lives in your **controller action's associated view**'s to submit the form data to a cake controller method asynchronyously. -- See: http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/
3. Adding the plugin just allows the plugin to handle the Model for you, right? Are you sure you need 2 invocations of the plugin? Or 2 controller actions or 2 controllers or 2 models or something that both use the plugin?
4. The view will return the data to the controller action, which is probably where you want to send it off to the model for handling. `beforeFilter()` is one of the controller callback methods; specifically, the one that fires just before any / every method in the controller (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html and  also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html for setting up your controller to handle async requests...)
5. Is thumbnail generation supposed to tax place on the frontend or the backend? >_> If it's the latter, do you need to add the code in your Model that generates the thumbnail from the data? Cake's magic model callbacks should make that pretty straightforward, too: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Trying it this way should at least simplify things for you.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (1.) I was hoping for the controller to sequentially send files to the model. (2.) This is somehow only working without the actAs-Behavior as this works with phps $_FILES. (3.) Unfortunately I have to use it once as actAs and once as new Uploader, as both behave very different. (5.) The backend it is. The thumbs would (if it would be working properly) be created by passing a paramter to the actAsBehaviour.   I will stick to the fat and happy controller approach i guess and keep you updated on my solution. Thanks alot again!

Comment: The controller does exactly that. When you call $this->Model, the Model object is where you're invoking it and it acquires the data automagically. actAs adds the Behavior to the Model, which is carried along when the controller calls it. You may have to spell out the Model callbacks explicitly, depending. They get overridden with certain advanced automagic (such as saveAll), and it sounds like that may be your problem.